# How to get exact menu items inside list?

Tags: flutter, api, listview

I have list of folders. There are different no. of data inside each folder. How can I get total no. of data from that folder in listview.
I tried to use 'snapshot.data!.data[index].length' but it gives error.
Any other way to show this?

Here is my code-

```
ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (BuildContext context) => MenuDetailPage(
                                          name: snapshot.data!.data[index]!.name,
                                          product: snapshot.data!.data[index].id,
                                        ),
                                      ),),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Row(
                                            children: [
                                              Flexible(
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children:[
                                                    Container(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                      height: 40.h,
                                                      width: 40.w,
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                                                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/MenuList.png", height: 30.h, width: 30.w,),
                                                    ),

                                                    //the item title and count
                                                    Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                          snapshot.data!.data[index].name,
                                                        ),
                                                        Row(
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                              'Item ${snapshot.data!.data[index].length Food Items}', // Update this line to display the item count
                                                            ),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),],),],),),);});
```

This is ListView-

[image]

This is the API for Menu list-

```
{
    "ignore": 0,
    "code": 1,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "menu123"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "menu123"
        },
    ]
}
```

This is the API for Data in the Menu-
http://dummydata.php?mid=1

```
{
    "ignore": 0,
    "code": 1,
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "ctg_id": "77",
            "name": "Baklawa",
            "items": [
                {
                    "prod_id": "1579",
                    "prod_name": "Kaju chocolate",
                    "thumb": "http:\/\/data.JPG"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You will need the API to change according to your requirement or else you can make another API call wherein you get the array of items and then only use total count of them.

Comment: add the error, data model and api call code in OP.